# Printing out a javascript variable (not showing up?)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to make sure a javascript variable is getting the correct values passed into it when setting it to a ruby variable.

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

   var test = <%= @test || 'null' %>;
   document.write(test);

</script>
```

However, there doesn't seem to be any output whatsoever. I've tried just `document.write("somethinganything")` and I still don't see any output. Is it supposed to appear on webpage or terminal? I couldn't find any in both.

Comment: If you use the browser's View Page Source option what does that code look like? The `@test` variable could contain a value that creates invalid JavaScript so then it would stop before it gets to the `document.write()`. Your `document.write("somethinganything")` should work, as you can see here: http://jsfiddle.net/Aa5nn/, unless you have _it_ after the same `var test = ...` line with an error.

Comment: what do you see if you view source? it is possible that the parser is stopping at the `var test ...` line due to some syntax error and never makes it to the following `document.write` line

Comment: Ended up using console.log, was able to track the variable value using firebug after. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`document.write` prints to the webpage. You should try using `console.log` to print to the terminal.

Comment: This doesn't answer the OP's question.  He didn't see any output in the document OR the terminal.

Comment: The only question in the question itself is "Is it supposed to appear on webpage or terminal? I couldn't find any in both."

Comment: So again this doesn't answer the question - why isn't it appearing in the webpage like it should?

Comment: @nnnnnn To know that we would need to have seen the HTML/CSS, and if it's something simple such as checking values you may as well just use a console.log.

Comment: @TheSmose You can use document.write() from the head section fyi.

Comment: @TheSmose I'm trying it inside notepad++ right now, with an empty body, and it's showing up in the top left hand corner of the page..

Comment: I apologize TheSmose. It was my fault for not explicitly stating what I really wanted to figure out. 

Although I was questioning why I couldn't see the output, my main concern was trying to find a way to see what the value of the variable was being set as. I just ended up giving the checkmark to whoever gave the answer first. 

I'll make sure to write down exactly what im looking for next time. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't use `document.write()` to print out visible content unless the script block is in the `<body>`.

Some older browsers will not support that, and if the script block is in the `<head>` it will not write anything visible.

Try one of the following solutions instead:

```
// Append a text node to the end of your body
window.onload = function() {
    var txt = document.createTextNode(test);
    document.body.appendChild(txt); 
};
```

or

```
// Log the text to your javascript console
console.log(test);
```

or

```
// Alert the text in a popup
window.alert(test);
```

Comment: `document.write()` works from script blocks in the `<head>` - do you have some supporting documentation for why you think it doesn't?

Comment: @nnnnnn I stand corrected.  Updated my answer to correct my statement.

Answer (score 1):

you have to write `console.log("test");`